# Is there any way to open url on android phone via only NFC not url address?

Tags: nfc, android-browser

I'm very new on NFC.

I realized NFC can open URL on browser.

But I want to hide my URL or prevent user that access via url address not NFC.

Is there any method to do this?

or method removing url history so that user cannot access by url.

please advise me :)

thanks.

Comment: Hi, What you have ended up with ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can hide a URL directly.

What you could to is create an app that contains a web browser element (WebView). In this WebView you could then display your website without exposing the URL (though, with some effort, users might still be able to find out the URL). Instead of using a URL on the NFC tag, you could then use Android's application record (AAR) facility to direct the user to the Play Store for installation of your app or open the app if it's already installed.